# How to Get Original Input in Blade Template in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, input, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

The original value of a field can be retrieved by `{{ old('my_field') }}`. But in my case, it's not enough. I'm working with dynamically added fields. Means, I cannot be sure, that the field `my_collection.5.my_field` exists. To get the error messages and the error formatting, I need to iterate over all dynamically added `fieldset`s:

```php
@if (request()->input('collection'))
    @foreach(request()->input('collection') as $key => $item)
    <label class="label" for="collection.{{ $key }}.my_field">my field</label>
    <textarea
        type="text"
        id="collection.{{ $key }}.my_field"
        name="collection[{{ $key }}][my_field]"
        class="textarea {{ $errors->has('collection.' . $key . '.my_field') ? 'is-danger' : '' }}">
        {{ old('collection.' . $key . '.my_field') }}
    </textarea>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

But the `request()->input('my_collection')` and `Input::get('my_collection')` return `null`. It also doesn't work for simple fields (`Input::get('my_simple_field')` and `Input::get('my_simple_field')`).

**How can I access the input fields in a Blade template?**

Comment: You need to use javascript based form submission

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but no, it won't help. I need to execute server-side code like `{{ old('actions.0.description') }}` (for displaying the original value) or `{{ $errors->has('actions.0.description') ? 'is-danger' : '' }}` (for marking the invalid fields). So I need the input fields in Blade first.

Comment: I'm just saying use ajax based submission and then get error from the server and render error on the same page with out reloading page

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand. But this it's really complicated and is more or less a workaround. What I want to implement, is just iterating over all dynamically added `fieldset`s and adding code (s. the example in the question). And it must work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (that suffices in this case) is the [`old(...)` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-old). It provides access to all the levels of the input <strike>(excepting the "root", means the input set itself)</strike>. So the functionality aimed in the question can be implemented as follows:

```
@if (old('actions'))
    @foreach(old('actions') as $key => $action)
        ...
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Nevertheless it would be nice to know, why `request()->input('my_collection')` and `Input::get('my_collection')` don't work and how to access the input set itself (e.g. in order to iterate over it).

---

**UPDATE**

The complete input set can be accessed with `old()` without arguments.